# Can I mock an exception that is replace in a custom error handler?

Tags: python, mocking, urllib2, python-mock

In an attempt to use `patch` from `mock` to write unit tests to validate our custom `urllib2` error handler that logs the error before raising a custom error, I cannot get the custom error to `raise`. The mocked exception will always `raise` after the log line in `LoggingErrorHandler` executes successfully. i.e. my test code is looking for `CustomError`, but the function still, surprisingly, raises the `urllib2.HTTPError`.

Test code:

```
@raises(CustomError)
def test_404_error_logging(self):
    ''' not the copy and paste code; enough to give you an idea '''
    http_error = urllib2.HTTPError("mock_url", 404, "Not Found", "mock_headers", None)
    with patch('function.that.invokes.error.handler', side_effect=http_error):
        test_client.get("bad url")
```

Custom error handler for urllib2 HTTPError handling:

```
class LoggingErrorHandler(urllib2.HTTPErrorProcessor):
    ''' not the copy and paste code; enough to give you an idea '''
    def http_error_404(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        log.debug("Look! An error! {0} {1}".format(code, msg))
        raise CustomError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, body, headers)
```

CustomError is also our custom exception.